# expect4j not waiting for full output

Tags: java, ssh, expect, blocking, jsch

I've using expect4j with JSch to connect to a remote shell and pull a config file. The code I'm using to connect to the machine is as follows:

```
    Session session = jsch.getSession(
            host.getUser(),
            host.toString(),
            SSH_PORT);
    session.setPassword(host.getPass());
    //If this line isn't present, every host must be in known_hosts
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
    channel.connect();
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    Expect4j expect = new Expect4j(in, out);
    for(String command : commands) { //List of commands
        int returnVal = expect.expect(prompts); //List of Match[] objects that correspond to different possible prompts
        if (returnVal != COMMAND_SUCCESS_OPCODE) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: tried to run " + command + " and got opcode " + returnVal);
        }
        expect.send(command);
        expect.send(ENTER_BUTTON); //Constant that corresponds to newline
    }
```

When run, the code gives me the following messages:

```
<Current Date & Time> expect4j.BlockingConsumer run
INFO: Stop Requested
<Current Date & Time> expect4j.BlockingConsumer run
INFO: Found EOF to stop while loop
```

I believe that the problem stems from that fact that it takes a second or two for the last command to complete. Is there a way to get expect4j to wait for the command to finish?

Additionally, the commands each return a different returncode from the expect command (0,1,2,2). Is there a place where I can look up those codes? Do they have any significance?

Comment: I suppose the command has finished when you can expect another prompt after sending the command, isn't the situation?

Comment: Could you elaborate/explain your comment? I haven't slept in far too long and I can't follow what your asking.

Comment: I suppose you're following this example http://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/

Comment: Not related to your question, but I think this tool is superior :-) just in case https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit

Comment: Yes, I am. Its the closest I could come to documentation.

Comment: Ill check out the linked library and give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is how I use it.

notice that since jsch-0.1.50, I had to start using this to make it work

```
    Hashtable<String,String> config = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    config.put("PreferredAuthentications", 
               "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");//makes kerberos happy
    session.setConfig(config);
```

So basically I use the very same code provided by the [tutorial](http://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/) except that my libraries are up to date

```
expect4j-1.0.jar
jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar
jsch-0.1.51.jar
```

And since my user is not root,

```
private static String[] linuxPromptRegEx = new String[]{"\\$"};
```

good luck

ps. I'd give [this alternative](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit) a try. Looks a very well made expect library.

Answer (score -1):

use expect4j 
expect4j not waiting for full output 
for example AIX's command 'prtconf'

Comment: do you mind to further clarify how that's been done?